# anisotropic and elliptic tori in GL(n)

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $F$ be a commutative field and $n\geqslant 2$ be an integer. It is well known that the maximal anisotropic mod center tori in $G={\rm GL}(n,F)$ are of the form $T = {\rm Res}_{E/F}\; {\mathbb G}_m$,for some degree $n$ separable field extension $E/F$,  where ${\rm Res}$ denotes Weil's restriction of scalar and where ${\mathbb G}_m$ denotes the $1$-dimensional split torus.

Such a torus $T$ embeds in $G$ in the following way. One identifies $G$ with ${\rm Aut}_F\; (E)$ and make $E^{\times} =T(F)$ acts on $E$ by multiplication.

One says that a torus is elliptic if it is not contained in any proper parabolic subgroup of $G$. The tori $T$ described above are  elliptic.

My question is :

> Is it true that the subtori of $T$ that are elliptic and anisotropic are of the form :
>   $S=\{  t\in T\ ; \ N_{E/L}(t)=1\}$, where $L/F$ is a proper subfield extension of $E/F$ ?

Comment: It would help me to have a reference or two to basic sources of this terminology.   My impression is that the notion of "elliptic torus" has only been studied over local fields, whereas "anisotropic torus" occurs more widely.   What is the context of your question? 

Comment: The max'l $F$-tori are $T_E := {\rm{Res}}_{E/F}(\mathbf{G}_m)$ for finite etale $F$-algebras $E$ of degree $n$, embedded via an ordered $F$-basis of $E$. Note $E = \prod E_i$ with fields $E_i$, so $T_E = \prod T_{E_i}$ and the max'l $F$-anisotropic subtorus is the product $\prod T_{E_i}^{1}$ of norm-1 subtori of factors. If at least 2 factor fields, it lies in a proper parabolic $F$-subgp, so not elliptic. Thus, elliptic anisotropic tori are contained in the elliptic anisotropic $T_E^1$ with $E/F$ a degree-$n$ sepble field extn. Do you really want the non-maximal examples too?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that using the term "elliptic torus" for a linear algebraic group is essentially begging to be misunderstood?

Comment: Dear Peter: The terminology is entirely standard, and despite knowing about tori and elliptic curves for a long time, it never crossed my mind that the phrase "elliptic torus" could create a misunderstanding. It is no worse than the fact that an elliptic curve is not an ellipse. So you may be the only one.  :)

Comment: @B: (Peter who??) Of course lots of people are confused by the fact that an elliptic curve is not an ellipse, but not people who are actually studying elliptic curves.  I imagine the same would hold here.  (To be fair, the phrase "complex torus" is even worse.)    

Comment: @Jim Humphreys. The problem arises indeed in the context of  local fields.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark. The term "elliptic torus" is standard in the theory of automorphic forms. 

Comment: @BCnrd OK, but I just miss the following argument. If $T$ is an anisotropic subtorus of ${\rm{Res}}_{E/F}(\mathbf{G}_m)$, why do we have $N_{E/F}\; (T)=1$ ?

Comment: Dear Paul: an anisotropic torus over a field has no nontrivial homomorphisms to $\mathbf{G}_m$ over the field, whence an anisotropic subtorus must be killed by the norm character.

Comment: @BCnrd It turns out that I need the non-maximal ones as well.